# Python Search File Returning []

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to search a JSON file for the username but it is just returning [] rather than tom123.

JSON file contents:

```
[{"id":"001788fffe48cbdb","username":"tom123"}]
```

Code:

```
import json
import re
import requests

f = open("first.json", "r+")
print(f.read())
username = [index["username"] for index in f.read()]
print(username)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`f` is a file object which is a iterator-like object, which means that when you iterate over it you've consumed it and you cannot use it again. And in this case you consume it first in following line:

```
print(f.read())
```

Also for loading a json file you should use `json.load()` function. Then you can preserve the content after reading then search though the preserved content:

```
with open("first.json") as f
    content = json.load(f)
    username = [index["username"] for index in content]
    print(username)
```

Also as a functional-based approach you can use `operator.itemgetter` and `map()` in order to get an iterator contain all the usernames (which is more optimized in terms of memory use):

```
from operator import itemgetter
with open("first.json") as f
        content = json.load(f)
        usernames = map(itemgetter("username"), content)
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this you want to parse the json so you can use it like a dict

```
import json
import re
import requests

f = open("first.json", "r+")
data = json.loads(f.read())
username = [index["username"] for index in data]
print(username)
f.close()
```